# Why doesn't the Controls collection provide all of the IEnumerable methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, extension-methods, ienumerable

I'm not for sure how the ControlCollection of ASP.Net works, so maybe someone can shed some light on this for me.

I recently discovered the magic that is extension methods and Linq. Well, I was very sad to find that this isn't valid syntax

```
var c=Controls.Where(x => x.ID=="Some ID").SingleOrDefault();
```

However from what I can tell, `Controls` does implement the `IEnumerable` interface which provides such methods, so what gives? Why doesn't that just work? I have found a decent work around for this issue at least:

```
var list = (IEnumerable<Control>)Controls;
var this_item = list.Where(x => x.ID == "Some ID").SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: You can do `list.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == "Some ID");`

Answer (score 96, accepted):

No, `IEnumerable` doesn't have many extension methods on it: `IEnumerable<T>` does. They are two separate interfaces, although `IEnumerable<T>` extends `IEnumerable`.

The normal LINQ ways of converting are to use the [`Cast<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) and [`OfType<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) extension methods which *do* extend the nongeneric interface:

```
IEnumerable<TextBox> textBoxes = Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
IEnumerable<Control> controls = Controls.Cast<Control>();
```

The difference between the two is that `OfType` will just skip any items which aren't of the required type; `Cast` will throw an exception instead.

Once you've got references to the generic `IEnumerable<T>` type, all the rest of the LINQ methods are available.

Answer (score 13):

This is just because the [`ControlCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.controlcollection.aspx) class came around before generics; so it implements `IEnumerable` but not `IEnumerable<Control>`.

Fortunately, there does exist a LINQ extension method on the `IEnumerable` interface that allows you to *generate* an `IEnumerable<T>` through casting: [`Cast<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx). Which means you can always just do this:

```
var c = Controls.Cast<Control>().Where(x => x.ID == "Some ID").SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Is there a reason it has not been updated to also implement `IEnumerable<Control>`? That shouldn't break backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the answers provided by Jon Skeet and Dan Tao, you can use query expression syntax by explicitly providing the type.

```
Control myControl = (from Control control in this.Controls
                    where control.ID == "Some ID"
                    select control).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 3):

Linq utilized Generic Collections.  ControlsCollection implements `IEnumerable` not `IEnumberable<T>`

If you notice this will not work

```
((IEnumerable)page.Controls).Where(...
```

However, this does

```
((IEnumerable<Control>)page.Controls).Where(...
```

You can either cast to Generic `IEnumerable<T>` or access an extension method that does, like so:

```
 page.Controls.OfType<Control>().Where(c => c.ID == "Some ID").FirstOrDefault();
```