# Linq cannot filter elements in loop

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I would like to filter the collection elements before I loop on each.

When I try this:

```
foreach (CheckBox checkbox in this.Controls()
        .Where(c => c.GetType() == typeof (CheckBox)).Select(c => (CheckBox)c))
```

I get the following error:

```
"System.Windows.Forms.Controls cannot be used like a method."
```

I use .NET framework 4 client-profile and for sure use `System.Linq` in code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Controls` is a property not a method also you can can do it much easier with [`Enumerable.OfType<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
foreach (CheckBox checkbox in this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
{
}
```

Comment: I get now 2 errors: `Foreach cannot operate on a 'method group'. Did you intend to invoke the 'method group'` and `foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'method group' because 'method group' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'`

Comment: Do you put brackets after `OfType`?

Comment: That's the spot! Thanks! However, why cannot use my code? My code is appropriate to what sort of collection? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code would be fine if `ControlCollection` would support `IEnumerable<T>` but is supports only `IEnumerable`. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302435/why-doesnt-the-controls-collection-provide-all-of-the-ienumerable-methods) question

Answer (score 4):

`this.Controls` is a property, not a method, so you should use it without the brackets `()`.

```
foreach (CheckBox checkbox in this.Controls
        .Where(c => c.GetType() == typeof (CheckBox)).Select(c => (CheckBox)c))
```

**Edit**: Based on your comment this does not work. What you could use is the following code:

```
foreach (var control in this.Controls)
{
    CheckBox myCheckbox = control as CheckBox;
    if (myCheckbox == null) continue;

    // your code
}
```

But I would also prefer the solution from [dkozi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22010920/2074649).

Comment: Thanks. Now I get this: `'System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Where'`